# JavaScript, Adding html to jQuery append function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to use jQuery to add buttons on a page. I would like the buttons to appear vertical instead of horizontal. So I try

```
 $(".guess").append("<p>" + guess_answer + "</p>");
```

But then it prints to the page:

[object Object]

[object Object]

[object Object]

[object Object]

Instead of the buttons. I have test the code without the paragraph tags and it works but doesn't when the html is place in it.

```
var question1 = {
    question: "What is 4 times 1?",
    answer: "Dream On",
    possible: [1,2,3,4],
    boolean: [true,false,false,false]
};


function generate () {
    $(".question").html(question1.question);

    for (var i = 0; i < question1.possible.length; i++) {       
        var guess_answer = $('<button>');
        guess_answer.addClass("options text-center btn-group-lg");
        guess_answer.attr({
            "data-boolean" : question1.boolean[i]
        });

        guess_answer.text(question1.possible[i]);
        //guess_answer.append(question1.possible[i]);

        $(".guess").append("<p>" + guess_answer + "</p>");
    }
}
```

Comment: It's being converted to its toString representation because you're adding to to a string. Why not use the same mechanism to add it as a child of your new paragraph the same way you already know how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `guess_answer.prop("outerHTML")` to get the element as HTML string

```
var question1 = {
    question: "What is 4 times 1?",
    answer: "Dream On",
    possible: [1,2,3,4],
    boolean: [true,false,false,false]
};


function generate () {
    $(".question").html(question1.question);

    for (var i = 0; i < question1.possible.length; i++) {       
        var guess_answer = $('<button>');
        guess_answer.addClass("options text-center btn-group-lg");
        guess_answer.attr({
            "data-boolean" : question1.boolean[i]
        });

        guess_answer.text(question1.possible[i]);
        //guess_answer.append(question1.possible[i]);

        $(".guess").append("<p>" + guess_answer.prop("outerHTML") + "</p>");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Glad to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Its because guess_answer as defined in your generate function contains a button object, you cannot append a HTML entity combining it with html tags using append.

If you want to add a button to the HTML, then simply write it in the append like so:

```
    $(".guess").append("<p><button value='123'/></p>");
```

However you should use the class name to append HTML content, whilst it is valid, a class might not be unique and if you add content with ID's then you may create multiple instances with the same ID which isn't valid.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `guess_answer` is an object, more specifically a jQuery object holding a DOM node.

Use DOM methods to insert it

```
function generate() {
    $(".question").html(question1.question);

    for (var i = 0; i < question1.possible.length; i++) {

        var guess_answer = $('<button />', {
            'class' : 'options text-center btn-group-lg',
            'data-boolean' : question1.boolean[i],
            text : question1.possible[i]
        }),
            p = $('<p />');

        $(".guess").append( p.append(guess_answer) );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried using `appendTo(...)` - like this

`guess_answer.appendTo('.guess');`

**See code below:**

```js
var question1 = {
  question: "What is 4 times 1?",
  answer: "Dream On",
  possible: [1, 2, 3, 4],
  boolean: [true, false, false, false]
};


function generate() {
  $(".question").text(question1.question);

  for (var i = 0; i < question1.possible.length; i++) {
    var guess_answer = $('<button>');
    guess_answer.addClass("options text-center btn-group-lg");
    guess_answer.attr({
      "data-boolean": question1.boolean[i]
    });

    guess_answer.text(question1.possible[i]);
    //guess_answer.append(question1.possible[i]);
    var newPar = $("<p>");
    
    newPar.appendTo('.guess');                    
    guess_answer.appendTo(newPar);    
  }
}

generate();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="question"></div>
<div class="guess"></div>
```